# Remaining Days with HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML 5 with CSS & JavaScript. I have been trying to execute countdown code which will give the remaining days and hours and minutes to a specific date entered. But I am not getting anything. Can anyone please help with my code? 
Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf=8" />
        <title> JavaScript </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function doIT() {
                setInterval(function countdown() {
                    now = new Date();
                    then = Date.parse(document.getElementById("date").value);
                    daysLeft = then - now;
                    days = Math.floor(daysLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    hours = Math.floor(daysLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                    mins = Math.floor(daysLeft / (1000 * 60));
                    secs = Math.floor(daysLeft / 1000);
                    dd = days;
                    hh = hours - days * 24;
                    mm = mins - hours * 60;
                    ss = secs - mins * 60;
                    document.getElementById("Countdown").innerHTML = dd + ' days ' + hh + 'hours' + mm + ' minutes ' + ss + ' seconds ';
                }, 1000);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Enter a date in the format "December 24, 2014" <br> (optionally add time, e.g., "17:00:00)
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" id="date" size="50" /> <br><br>
        <button onclick="doIt()">GO</button><br><br>
        <div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:400px; height:50px, border:2px solid; line-height:24px;font-family:Arial;">
            Countdown:<br>
            <div id="Countdown"> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated in revealing the mysteries of web coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function name in the definition or call is wrong

Defined with `doIT` but associated in the button as `doIt` :)